# Expected endmodule error while definig macro

Tags: macros, verilog, system-verilog

I have defined a macro for gating gating assertion but while compiling, I am facing failure saying: endmodule expected at endproperty.

Code:

```
`define gating_check( _name, _clock, _data, txen) \
property _name ; \
@(posedge `TOP.``_clock``) disable iff (~`STIMULUS.RSTN_VEC_GEN) \
(~(txen) |-> ##[1:6] ( |`TOP.``_data`` == 0 ) ); \ 
endproperty \ 
``_name``_checker : assert property (_name) else $error("-E- property gating_check failed"); \
``_name``_cover : cover property (_name)
```

Pls help.

Comment: I have formated with code block, not sure if all the backticks are intended.

Answer (score 1):

You just have extra space after the "\" in two lines  - 4 and 5 ,  if you remove these trailing space the code should compile.

The "\" is used to escape the end of line but an extra space after the "\" will not do so. Hence now your macro has become a multi-lien statement generating the error. Because its a space character it difficult to observe :) .

Below is the code without the trailing space in line 4 and 5 .

```
`define gating_check( _name, _clock, _data, txen) \
property _name ; \
@(posedge `TOP.``_clock``) disable iff (~`STIMULUS.RSTN_VEC_GEN) \
(~(txen) |-> ##[1:6] ( |`TOP.``_data`` == 0 ) ); \
endproperty \
``_name``_checker : assert property (_name) else $error("-E- property gating_check failed"); \
``_name``_cover : cover property (_name)
```